# multiple action="pages from diffrent domains" in sigle form

Tags: javascript, html, css

multiple action="pages from different domains" in single form, according to select option action pages should change on single submit, please help me with example code
note:want use only one submit button

Comment: You need to break this down into a) A question, b) An example of what you have so far. Right now it's very hard to understand exactly what you even want to do

Comment: If I understand you correctly then the only way to submit a single form to multiple action locations would be by using Ajax.

Comment: [link](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/282034-how-change-include-path-on-diffrent-select-option/) pls check this link i posted code here give me code exxample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AJAX, try to submit the form to one url, on it's success handle submit to next domain and so on.

eg.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: "id="+id+"&id-other="+id-other, //Setting the values for submit.
    url: "URL1.php"
}).done(function(data){
    $("#div").html(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: "id_1="+id+"&id_2="+id_2,
        url:"URL2.php"
    }).done(function(data){
        //Do whatever you want to after success.
    });
});
```

Comment: i did not understand that i am in hello world stage .....

Comment: for example : i have main form1 it has domain1 variable in that for  user has option to select domain1 or other domain2 so if user select other domain2 it should submit for  domain2 where the form is located  with domain 2 variable in it

Comment: all should happen from domain one so i can add more form from other domains

Comment: for example [link](http://xtgem.com/user/register)

Comment: [link](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/282034-how-change-include-path-on-diffrent-select-option/) please check this link i posted my code here

Comment: So do you want to change the domain everytime, but at one time only one domain would be present?

Comment: ya whenever the user selects domain choice he must get register from that particular domain means page should be pulled from selected domain via options

Comment: i think i need to create a page and set array for each url